# What is the difference between using the terminal to install software vs the software-center/gui?

Tags: software-installation

What is the difference between using these two, or are they exactly the same?

If I install something in in the command prompt can it then get updates via the GUI, and vice versa for GUI installed software?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as by "command line" you mean the `apt-get install` or `aptitude install` commands, it's the same as installing using Software Center: 
under the covers they all use the same software management system (APT),
so you will get the updates whichever way you use.

Comment: Thank you, this was very informative. Is updating through the Software Updater the same as running "apt-get update" and then "apt-get upgrade"? Or dist-upgrade?

Comment: Terminal usage provides more functionality compared to Software Center usage. If you are keen to use terminal, you would handle installing packages effectively.

Answer (score 0):

well its simple Linux are giving they users the option how they want update the system means that they can use the terminal or the software updater to update,upgrade and install anything and everything

hope that help :)

Answer (score 0):

When you browse the software center and find software to install it'll execute the `apt-get install` command followed by whatever package you're downloading. But the software center can also be used to install .deb files, where it executes the `dpkg -i` command followed by the path to the .deb file.

`apt-get install packagename` to install from your repositories

`dpkg -i path_to_deb_file` to install .deb files

eksamples:

```
sudo apt-get install htop

sudo dpkg -i /home/user/Downloads/package.deb
```